# Prove or give a counter example for the following statements.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Given that $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\vec{b} \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $\vec{b} \neq \vec{0}$ and the equation $A \vec{x}= \vec{b}$ only has one solution, how do we prove/disprove the following statements?

1.

$$\|A \vec{x}\| = \|A^TA \vec{x}\|$$
 2.
 $$\|A \vec{x}\| = \|A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T \  \vec{b}\|$$

Comment: Your second statement is missing.

Comment: I can see it from my side. Let me see what the problem is.

Comment: For the second statement, make use of the identity $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$

Comment: @NicholasRoberts, the identity only works if $A$ and $B$ are invertible, which isn't true for a non-square matrix.

Comment: Hint: At least one of these has a counterexample among the scalars, i.e. with $m=n=1$.